# Speeding up monte carlo code in python

Tags: python, optimization

Consider points Y given in increasing order from [0,T). We are to consider these points as lying on a circle of circumference T. Now consider points X also from [0,T) and also lying on a circle of circumference T.

We say the distance between X and Y is the sum of the absolute distance between the each point in X and its closest point in Y recalling that both are considered to be lying in a circle. Write this distance as Delta(X, Y).

I am trying to find a quick way of approximating the distributions of distance between the circles over all possible rotations of X.  I am currently does this by Monte Carlo simulation. First here is my code to make some fake data.

```
import random
import numpy as np
from bisect import bisect_left

def simul(rate, T):
    time = np.random.exponential(rate)
    times = [0]
    newtime = times[-1]+time
    while (newtime < T):
        times.append(newtime)
        newtime = newtime+np.random.exponential(rate)
    return times[1:]
```

Now the code the find the distance between two circles.

```
def takeClosest(myList, myNumber, T):
    """
    Assumes myList is sorted. Returns closest value to myNumber in a circle of circumference T.

    If two numbers are equally close, return the smallest number.
    """
    pos = bisect_left(myList, myNumber)
    if (pos == 0 and myList[pos] != myNumber):
        before = myList[pos - 1] - T
        after = myList[0]
    elif (pos == len(myList)):
        before = myList[pos-1]
        after = myList[0] + T
    else:
        before = myList[pos - 1]
        after = myList[pos]
    if after - myNumber < myNumber - before:
        return after
    else:
        return before

def circle_dist(timesY, timesX):
    dist = 0
    for t in timesX:
        closest_number = takeClosest(timesY, t, T)
        dist += np.abs(closest_number - t)
    return dist
```

Now the main code to make the data and to try 1000 different random rotations.

```
T = 50000
timesX = simul(1, T)
timesY = simul(10, T)

dists=[]
iters = 100
for i in xrange(iters):
       offset = np.random.randint(0,T)
       timesX = [(t+offset) % T for t in timesX]
       dists.append(circle_dist(timesY, timesX))
```

We can now print out any statistics we like of the distances. I am particularly interested in the variance.

```
print "Variance is ", np.var(dists)
```

Unfortunately I need to do this a lot and it takes around 16 seconds currently.  I find this a little surprising it is so slow. Any suggestions for how to speed it up gratefully received.

---

**Edit 1.** Reduced the number of iterations to 100 (the previous value didn't correspond to my timings correctly). This now takes around 16 seconds on my computer.

**Edit 2.** Fixed bug in takeClosest

Comment: have you tried [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/)?

Comment: [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is more appropriate for these types of questions.

Comment: @Aprillion Thanks an interesting suggestion. Thank you. I was hoping their might be some python/numpy/scipy speed up before I went down that route as there is a problem with portability with numba.

Comment: First you have to profile your code to see which operations are taking the lasrgest time to execute.

Comment: hmm.. `circle_dist` is `O(n*logn)` and I don't see a way to make the algorithm any faster - but you can try making `times` a numpy array of floats instead of python array of dynamic types..

Comment: @rano - generally that would be a good advice, but there's only 1 nested loop in this code, what do you hope can be learned from profiling? perhaps if `bisect_left` is not implemented as an actual `O(logn)` binary search, but there's some mistake that makes it `O(n)`...

Comment: Unfortunately your code is not running. ```bisect_left``` and ```poisson_simul``` are undefined. (The latter is probably ```simul```. Oh and I found the first one: An import was missing.) For a quick code review it's always nice to copy/paste a piece of code and it just works.

Comment: @Falko Sorry about that. Fixed now I hope.

Comment: `takeClosest` doesn't appear to actually use `T`; is that intentional?

Comment: What kind of speedup are you looking for?  There are tricks, like saving attribute lookups in local variables, etc. but they will only get you so far..

Comment: @thebjorn If one could get a factor of 10 that would be great. In fact I only really want an estimate for the variance but I can't think of a faster way of getting it.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel That was left over from before I learned about using -1 as an index. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel good spot, `T` is actually required to compute the correct value of distance - the implementation in the question is not correct (see my edited answer).

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: I've just noticed that performance optimization is a little premature, because the expression `closest_number - t` is not a valid implementation of any definition of a `distance` on a "circle" - that is only a distance on an open-ended line

sample test case (pseudocode):

```
T = 10
X = [1, 2]
Y = [9]
dist(X, Y) = dist(1, 9) + dist(2, 9)
dist_on_line   = 8 + 7 = 15
dist_on_circle = 2 + 3 = 5
```

Note that definition of the circle `[0,10)` implies that `dist(0, 10)` is not defined, but in the limit it approaches 0: `lim(dist(0, t), t->10) = 0`

[image: circle distance illustration]

A correct implementation of a distance on a circle would be:

```
dist_of_t = min(t - closest_number_before_t,
                closes_number_after_t - t,
                T - t + closes_number_before_t,
                T - closest_number_after_t + t)
```

---

Original answer:

you could rotate and iterate over `timesY` instead of `timesX` since that array is an order of magnitude smaller - doing `bisect_left` of `timeX` is negligible (`O(logn)`) compared to iterating over all the elements (`O(n)`)

but IMHO, the real slowdown if because of Python dynamic typing (every of the ~50000 items in `timesX` has to be checked for type compatibility each time you try to compare it to some other value) => converting `timesX` and `timesY` to numpy arrays should help, if that is not enought CPU acceleration (cython, numba, ...) is the think you need

Comment: Great idea. Looks like the time improvement is about 90 % when switching the rates for ```timesX``` and ```timesY```. I'm not sure if there is any impact on the result. So it's up to the OP.

Comment: I am happy to switch to numpy arrays but I can't switch the order of comparison. You get a completely different answer.

Comment: Simply switching to timesX = np.array(simul(1, T))
timesY = np.array(simul(10, T)) **doubled** the time . Then changing from bisect_left to np.searchsorted increased the time by another 50% ... :(

Comment: I'm no expert in `numpy`, so I have no idea why that's slower than pure Python.. but if simply by switching the order you get a different results, the result you get cannot be defined as the `distance between X and Y` - at most, it could be "distance of X from Y", but not "between ... and ..." => are you sure you are implementing a correct definition of the distance??

Comment: ah, I found the problem with your distance implementation, see my edited answer.

Comment: You are quite right. I have hopefully fixed that now. It's not a formal distance function. As you say it's an asymmetric measure of similarity. I could make it symmetric by just doing X, Y and Y,X and summing them but I don't think that helps me.

Comment: How did you draw the lovely picture by the way?

Comment: for the picture, I used Excel pie chart with 3 series `{3,3,4}, {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}, {4,2,4}` (the one that looks like doughnut can use multiple series), edited colors (white for the "transparent" parts), removed all labels, copied as picture and flip-flopped it around (so the area on top is continuous) and added labels manually

Comment: OK I give in :) I managed to install numba. Any idea how to get my code to use it?

Answer (score 1):

The function `circle_dist` can be replaced by a one-liner. So you can plug it into your outer `for i` loop:

```py
sum(abs(takeClosest(timesY, t) - t) for t in timesX)
```

Furthermore, you should always - if possible - allocate arrays like `dists` in one step and avoid appending elements many thousand times.

But, unfortunately, both improvements only save a few percent of computing time.

**Edit 1:** Replacing `np.abs(...)` with `abs(...)` decreases computing time by **50 %** on my machine (on a reduced data set)!

**Edit 2:** Updated the one-liner according to Aprillion's comment.

Comment: you could also replace the list comprehension `[]` by a generator `sum(np.abs...` to save some memory

Comment: @Aprillion: Oh you mean ```sum(abs(takeClosest(timesY, t) - t) for t in timesX)```? Cool. I wasn't aware of that this is possible. :)